PLL controls frequency or phase?
I have a slight confusion about the working of the PLL. I have been following this document about digital PLL. I want to use PLL to get the same frequency and phase as that of a grid for a grid synchronized inverter using STM32F4, but I have the following confusions regarding the PLL.

Does PLL initially when the system is not locked gives the samples of the sinusoidal wave of same frequency the one I passed when the loop is opened? I mean I want to give these samples to my SPWM so in case of open loop I mean will I be able to get a sinusoidal wave directly of same frequency and just the phase changed?
Secondly In case of PLL like I am confused about the fact that frequency can simply be detected by taking samples directly from a signal and regenerate the wave. Can I say that PLL just shifts the wave forward and backwards? I am not understanding why do I need to change the frequency when simply sampling can give me the exact frequency wave apart from setting the phase in next step.
What is the purpose of the Wo in the VCO section shown below. Why do I need this offset. Kindly help me understand this.

I may be asking some very basic questions but I am having confusions regarding these. It would be very good If I get some favorable answers to implement in my STM32F4.

